# CSS Ratings Bar on the same line

Tags: css

I am creating a ratings bar and i currently have this code

```
<div class="rating-bar">
    <div style="background-color:#00ff00;height:30px;width:4%; margin-left:20px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#ff0000;height:30px;width:2%; margin-left:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the `#00FF00` shows on one line, and the `#ff0000` shows on another.
how can i make them be side by side, so left side `#00ff00` and right `#ff0000`, no matter the width, like youtube's bar.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use inline styling.... honestly, most people just skip questions that use inline styling because it's harder to follow.

Comment: .rating-bar div {
    float:left;
}

Comment: I've tried this but there is still a space between the colours http://jsfiddle.net/e2keE/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e2keE/1/, yes because of margins... now should be ok?

Comment: This worked, list it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.rating-bar div { float:left; }
```

and Remove the  margin-left:20px; from inline styles also add clear:left

```
<div class="rating-bar">
    <div style="background-color:#00ff00;height:30px;width:4%;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#ff0000;height:30px;width:2%; "></div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to give them a `display:inline-block`, this lets you set the width and the height of them. See [What is inline block](http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/) for more details.

Also, if you want to get rid of the space between the elements, see [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). Personally I like setting the font size, messing around with comments or structuring the markup is nasty.